# pushing multi dimentional array within array js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have declared an array variable and I want to push new data but it doesn't work. below is my code

```
let locations = [
  [2.4333,4.45333],
  [3.45454,5.222325]
]
```

here is the code pushing to `locations` variable

```
 for (var j=0;j<res.length;j++) {
    locations.push([res[j]['lat'], res[j]['long']])
    //4.3333, 4.33444
 }
```

and this is the code to display

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1])
}
```

This is what I'm getting in console log

```
> Array[]
console.log(locations.length)// 0
```

Thanks

Comment: please add the error, you get.

Comment: Print out a `res[j]`.

Comment: Can you `console.log(res)` after the 'code pushing to locations variable' code. Then you will know if it is an issue with adding, or displaying

Comment: `position: new ...` is not a JS statement. `position = ...` ? What do you mean by "doesn't work" ?

Comment: I've put a console log message. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have used the wrong variable in loop.

```
for (var j=0;j<res.length;j++) {
    latlong.push([res[j]['lat'], res[j]['long']])
 }
```

Comment: Where is `latlong` defined?

Comment: @JMadelaine I am assuming he has already used the data structure for latlong in array of objects

let res = [{"lat":"112", "long":"123"},{"lat":"112","long":"123"}]

Answer (score 1):

With some assumptions.

```js
var res = [{ lat: 1234, long: 4567 }, { lat: 2234, long: 5567 }];
var locations = [
    [2.4333, 4.45333],
    [3.45454, 5.222325]
];
for (var j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
    locations.push([res[j]['lat'], res[j]['long']])
}
console.log(locations);
```

Comment: Did you check with `Run Code Snippet` or while running in your dev environment?